# is there a special search command for options and commands in man-pages (in less)?

Tags: search, manpage, less-unix

Question: using the less command in any linux shell (i'm using bash as probably most people do), is there a way to search a file only for it's commands or options?

So, to be more precise:
if i want to quickly find the description for one special option in a man-page,
is there a special search syntax to quickly jump to the corresponding line explaining that specific command?

example:

if i type:

```
man less
```

and i want to quickly find the description for the "-q" command,
is there a search syntax to directly jump to that line?
If I type `/-q`, it finds all occurences of "-q" everywhere in the file, so I get around 10-20 hits, of which only one is the one i was looking for..

So I'm just hoping there is a better/quicker way to do this..
(not to important though :D)

Comment: Whoever is asking to close this question as general-software-related is probably not familiar with Unix. The `man` command is a first-class helper when it comes to developing (C and shell-scripting) under Unix.

Answer (score 2):

In `man`, options are generally described with the option name in bold at the start of the line.

So, if you are looking for the option `-q`, then the search command would be `/^\s*-q\>`

The regex `^\s*-q\>` reads as follow:

- `^` start of a line
- `\s*` any number of spaces (including none)
- `-q` the option name you are looking for
- `\>` the end of the word

Answer (score 0):

There're several possible solutions for the requested direct jump to the line with the option's description.

### Strait-forward solution

Prepend your search query with a space(s): `/ -q` will find option's description right away.

### Piping to `less`

According to the [less documentation](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html), you can use `-p` or `+` option for jumping to the search string. Quoting the documentation:

> The -p option on the command line is equivalent to specifying +/pattern; that is, it tells less to start at the first occurrence of pattern in the file.

So the following example commands will "jump" to the option's description too.

```bash
man ls | less -p "  -L"
```

```bash
man ls | less "+/  -L"
```

### Extract into a function

To save us keystrokes, a good idea would be to write a shell (`bash` in this case) function that would call one of the above commands. For instance, see the basic example:

```bash
manopt()
{
    if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
        echo "Enter command name and option to search for."
    else
        man "$1" | less "+/  $2"
    fi
}
```

After ["sourcing"](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) this function, search for `less` command `-q` option description with the following:

```bash
manopt less -q
```